# leer archivo csv llenar un formulario

Tags: php, csv

estoy necesitando automatizar un proceso, necesito leer un archivo csv (generado por un excel) y poder volcarlo automaticamente en un formulario web php común.

¿es posible realizarlo con estas herramientas?

la idea seria, ingresar a un formulario, y que al momento de ejecutar el codigo, este formulario lea un archivo csv (o algun otro formato que pueda crear en excel) y envie los datos guardados a un mail asignado mediante la carga automatica.

Comment: Si se puede hacer, pero deberías mostrar algo que hayas intentado o algún avance de lo que hayas hecho, recuerda que esta comunidad es para ayuda a problemas puntuales.

Comment: Hola, la respuesta concreta a tu pregunta es si, si es posible, para poder ayudarte mejor, necesitamos que nos compartas un problema en especifico acompañado del código que estes utilizando, saludos.

Comment: por ejemplo, tengo el formato csv con este estilo

Comment: @M.Gress por ejemplo

tengo el csv con este formato
   `juan perez,active,122334543,prueba,prueba`

necesito que el php lo lea, y rellene estos campos automaticamente
  
    `$data["customer_contact_name"]`
   `$data["customer_contact_lastname"]`
    `$data["customer_contact_email"]`

Comment: @krylogger Si es posible, pero ¿Cómo lo estas intentando? Lo primero que deberias de considerar es buscar cómo leer un archivo en PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa este código copiado de la definición de fgetcsv de la documentación de PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```